# Why onmousedown is not working on empty gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added a box collider to the gameobject.
And yet the onmousedown in the script never trigger.

[image: Back]

And the script Back

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Back : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectstexts;
    public Rotate rotate;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        rotate.StartRotations();
    }
}
```

The gameobject back is not a cube it's not the cube I want to click on.
I'm using the Back empty gameobject just to get it's name for switching the name on the bottom cube. From Quit to Back.

The back empty gameobject is positioned at the same place of the Quit cube.

Comment: In order for something to be clickable, it has to be renderable. It's difficult to determine from your question, but it sounds as though you have a non-renderable object that you want to be able to click on. How do you click an invisible object?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script is attached to the game object you want to be clickable.
Make sure you have an enabled collider
Make sure you have not resized or changed the position of the collider
Make sure there are no other colliders in the way. OnMouseDown() works just like a Raycast()...the first thing hit is what gets the OnMouseDown().

If everything looks okay and it still does not work, delete the object and start over by adding the new object, adding the script...

Answer (score 0):

The very first statement on the API of [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) says

> `OnMouseDown` is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the `GUIElement` or `Collider`.

Your **empty** GameObject didn't have any those.

You could for example add a `BoxCollider` to it, though the usability of an invisible button is very questionable. The main issue now might however be that the other cube is in front of this collider so you never actually hit it.

It is blocked by the other cube